# Run a program and then resize the window using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I currently have the following AutoHotKey-script:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
WinWait, MINGW64:/
WinActivate
WinMove A, , , , 735, 640
```

This runs `git-bash.exe`, waits for it to be completely opened, activates the opened window and resizes it to width 735 and height 640. This works as long as I only execute it once. When I run that script a second time, when a `git-bash.exe`-window is already present, the resize does not work because it resizes the first window. How can I resize the just opened window?

Answer (score 4):

> Run, Target [, WorkingDir, Max|Min|Hide|UseErrorLevel, OutputVarPID]

`Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe",,, PID`

> WinWait [, WinTitle, WinText, Seconds, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]

`WinWait, ahk_pid %PID%`

> WinActivate [, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]

`WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%`

> WinMove, WinTitle, WinText, X, Y [, Width, Height, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]

`WinMove, ahk_pid %PID%, , , , 735, 640`

Finished Script:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe",,, PID
WinWait, ahk_pid %PID%
WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID%
WinMove, ahk_pid %PID%, , , , 735, 640
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The `git-bash`-window is opened but not resized. I tried it with "C:Windows\system32\cmd.exe" instead and it works with this, so the reason is the `git-bash.exe`. But why would it work with my previous script (which I mentioned in the question) for the first window only?

Comment: I'll look into this, but it's likely an issue with git-bash not the AutoHotkey code, which as you said works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Autohotkey command **WinGet, window, ID, A**

This will Retrieves your **Windows ID**

The Code Will Looks Like this:

```
Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
WinWaitActive, MINGW64:/
sleep 250
WinGet, window, ID, A
WinMove, ahk_id %window%, , ,735,640
return
```

note: the commandline sleep 250 you will need, When you run that script for a second time (if the first [git-bash.exe] window is already present)